# iOS - How can I detect that the current wifi needs to go through a confirmation screen?

Tags: ios, wifi, connectivity

Quite often when joining a public wifi you need to go through a confirmation screen before getting access to the broad Internet. Most of the time after connecting through Settings, you'd open Safari just to do that confirmation before using your apps.

How can I detect this state from my app and show a web view to let the user do that form the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this URL:  https://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html
If you get HTTP statuscode 200, and something other than 'Success' in response, then you're probably talking to a captive portal.

Or you can of course create your own hotspot-detect page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Success</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
Success
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Nice. Do you know of some documentation on this ? Could not find any :(

Comment: I couln't find official documentation too, but Apple devices are querying this URL each time when you connect to a wifi network. If the response is something other than 'Success' the device shows the response (probably a loginpage) in a WebView popup.
But you can of course use your own URL too if you don't want to use https://captive.apple.com/hotspot-detect.html See my updated answer.